# Algorithm to print all permutations of a string with no duplicates

Tags: string, algorithm

Can you give me an algorithm to print all permutations of a string, with no duplicates, both recursively and iteratively?

Comment: SO isn't going to just give you code.

Comment: What have you tried? and is this homework? SO is about helping you with problems, not giving you code and doing your work for you. And a quick google search shows me like 3-4 different examples for this that you could have used.

Comment: I'm sure that someone could, but StackOverflow is not a **give me teh codez** site. Try for yourself and post here when you run into a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a good question since permutations are used fairly frequently and can be hard to implement especially without redundancies. Of course the algorithm is pretty simple. Here is a good site to help you out (after googling around for a second). Check it out, hope its what you are looking for! http://www.bearcave.com/random_hacks/permute.html

Comment: Its not a good question at all, he asks for code without any examples or what he has tried, its a duplicate of like three other exact questions and doesnt show any prior research. Read the FAQ.